# Как создать список в telegram bot на aiogram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я хочу чтобы пользователь по нажатию кнопки или ввода команды получал список(например магазинов), в котором он должен будет выбрать что-то одно, после чего выбранный текст отправляется для последующей обработки.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать и если знаете где вообще смотреть какую-либо информацию по aiogram(смотрел документацию, либо она для меня слишком сложная, либо там очень скудно всё описано) подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то
Просто сделайте это через инлайн кнопки, которые при нажатии будут выдавать колбек дату, которую вы потом будете обрабатывать в колбек хендлере.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["magazine"])
async def open_magazines(msg: types.Message):
    magazines = {
        "Магазин1": "magaz1",
        "Магазин2": "magaz2",
    }
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    for name, data in magazines.items():
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(name, callback_data=data))
    await msg.answer("Магазины", reply_markup=markup)
```

Писал с телефона возможны ошибки

Comment: А как добавить возможность скролить, если элементов много?

Comment: @danil_kri Конкретно скролить - никак. Но можно сделать две инлайн кнопки типа вперёд и назад которые меняют маркап клавиатуры.

Comment: а вообще можно добавить что-то, что имеет возможность скролинга?

Comment: Нет, только то что я писал выше. Вы по факту делаете "страницы" на каждой из которых будет некоторое количество кнопок и при нажатии на "вперёд" будет меняться вся клавиатура.